# BotFramework-WebChat Replace chat avatar with placeholder

Tags: javascript, botframework

I want to change the chat avatar, and the avatar of the bot, but setting the backgroundImage doesn't work  [image]

```
var styleSet = window.WebChat.createStyleSet({
    backgroundColor: '#f3f3f3',
    bubbleBackground: '#FFFFFF',
    bubbleBorderRadius: 5,
    bubbleTextColor: 'Black',
    bubbleFromUserBackground: '#3a8dde',
    bubbleFromUserBorderRadius: 5,
    bubbleFromUserTextColor: 'White',

});
styleSet.avatar = {
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: '50%',
    color: 'white',
    backgroundColor: 'gray',


    display: 'flex',
    height: "50px",
    justifyContent: 'center',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    width: "50px"
};

window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({token: 'My.Secret.token'}),
    //styles
    styleSet: styleSet,
    botAvatarInitials: 'BF',
    userAvatarInitials: 'WC'

}, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

Comment: Please add the tag of the chat framework or library you're using. The javascript tag alone is to broad for this question

Comment: "setting the backgroundImage doesn't work" << where are you doing this in your code? Are you talking about the color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no solution for setting background images, but there is a workaround you can use with idiosyncratic styling, originally shared [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1456) on GitHub.

```
import { createStyleSet } from 'botframework-webchat;

const styleSet = createStyleSet({});
styleSet.avatar = {
    ...styleSet.avatar,
    '&.from-user': { 
         backgroundImage:'url(\'https://github.com/compulim.png?size=64\')' 
    },
   '&:not(.from-user)': {     
       backgroundImage:'url(\'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/v4sdk/media/logo_bot.svg?view=azure-bot-service-4.0\')' }
    };
};

<ReactWebChat
  botAvatarInitials= ' '
  userAvatarInitials= ' '
  styleSet={styleSet}`
/>
```

In JavaScript, you can do the following:

```
const styleSet = window.WebChat.createStyleSet();
  styleSet.avatar = { 
      ...styleSet.avatar,
     '&.from-user': { 
         backgroundImage:'url(\'https://github.com/compulim.png?size=64\')' 
      },
     '&:not(.from-user)': {     
         backgroundImage:'url(\'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/v4sdk/media/logo_bot.svg?view=azure-bot-service-4.0\')' }
      };

  window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
     directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
     styleSet,
     botAvatarInitials: ' ',
     userAvatarInitials: ' '
}, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

Comment: thank you, but i add   backgroundImage: 'url(${https://github.com/compulim.png?size = 64})'  to styleSet.avatar,   It doesn't seem to work.  botAvatarInitials: '',userAvatarInitials: ' ', I use this way now, it looks good.

Comment: The url needs to resolve to a string, so ```‘url(https://github.com/compulim.png’)``` should work.

Comment: Thanks, it looks good.  but user avatar and machine avatar look the same, how to set it different?

Comment: I just edited my original with more information, hope that helps!